# Unnest a JSon Object returned from api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I remove the nested json object returned from an api as shown below and show it as individual fields by unnesting the object using jquery in a generic way. here is my json object

```
 "response": {
"content": 
"[ {    
      "Id": 0,    
     "Name": "Some name",    
     "createdOnDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",      
    "keyValueList": 
      [      
           {        
             "Key": "key1",        
            "Value": "Sample Data key 1"      
            },      
           {        
            "Key": "key2",        
           "Value": "sample data key 2   
      ] }]"
```

this is how it should be after unnesting.

```
[{
    "Id": 123,
        "Name": "some name",
        "createdOnDate": "2013-01-22T17:02:00",
        "key1": "this is my key1",
        "key2": "this is my key2"

}]
```

Comment: you want to assign them to separate variables. or do you only want to keep the first one explain please

Comment: only keep the first one. don't want to add separate variables.

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid JSON. Make sure you're getting valid before. 
Afterwards you can iterate through the attributes and set them the way you want.

```
$.each(content[0]['keyValueList'], function (k, value) {
    content[0][value['Key']] = value['Value']
});

delete content[0]['keyValueList'];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TjQzv/3/

Comment: It's true, but it should be a comment (I'm expecting clarification from the asker)

Comment: I was manually typing so might have missed the format. yes. I am validating the json. how can I unnest and show the key value pairs as individual fields?

Comment: @user2221069 please correct the format. Also, see rcdmk's comment.